# Error: "No data exists for the row/column" using OdbcDataReader

Tags: c#, odbc, datareader

Even though I know that there is data for the exact SQL query I'm performing, for the fact that I am doing the SQL query directly on the database, I continually get an exception saying that no data exists. My code is below:

```
      try
        {
            dbConnection.Open();

            // Process data here.
            OdbcCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
            dbCommand.CommandText = "select forename from tblperson where personcode in (select clientcode from tblclient) and surname = '######'";
            OdbcDataReader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();

            Console.WriteLine(dbReader.GetString(0));

            dbReader.Close();
            dbCommand.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            dbConnection.Close();
        }
```

Can anyone give me reasons as to why this would be happening. The query should return a single result, and I'm currently only doing this to ensure that it is working, which it doesn't appear to be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After `ExecuteReader` is called, the reader is positioned **before** the first returned record.  To read the first record you need to call `Read()`

```
dbReader.Read()
```

Or of course if there are multiple rows:

```
while (dbReader.Read())
```